# Border wrapping wrong element in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add a border to some controls in XAML - the problem is, whenever I apply  wrapping a certain element it wraps the whole window, probably on the first grid element?

This also happens when I try to use it around the WebBrowser. Any suggestions?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="RAT-t00l" Height="850" Width="700">
    <Grid x:Name="BigGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="682">

        <TextBox Name="txt_Log" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="657" Margin="4,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="417" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Button Name="btn" Click="btn_Connect_Click" Background="LightGreen" Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="266,680,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Name="btn_disc" Click="btn_Disconnect_Click" Background="Pink" Content="Disconnect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="346,680,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Name="btn_fetch" Click="btn_Fetch_Click" Content="Fetch data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="266,707,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="24"/>
        <Button Name="btn_eraseLog" Click="btn_EraseLog_Click" Content="Erase log from target" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="266,736,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="25"/>



            <WebBrowser 

            Name="map"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Height="347"
                    Margin="426,10,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Width="246"
                    LoadCompleted="wb_LoadCompleted"

                    />
```

> ```
> Here's the border. Meaning to wrap only the grid inside.
> ```

```
        <Border Name="mask" CornerRadius="20" Height="auto" Width="auto" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <Grid x:Name ="GeneralGrid" Margin="426,362,10,291" ShowGridLines="True" Background="LightGray">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="61*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="185*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="IP">IP</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Name="ISP" Grid.Row="1">ISP</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="Location" Grid.Row="2">Location</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="Longitude" Grid.Row="3">Longitude</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="Latitude" Grid.Row="4">Latitude</TextBlock>

        </Grid>

    </Border>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: A border may 'wrap' components, but it is also positioned within its parent. It won't move to where it's children are positioned, it is placed according to the usual `Grid.Column`, `Grid.Row`, `Grid.ColumnSpan`, `Grid.RowSpan` and `Margin` properties. Have a look at how your border is positioned with regards to `BigGrid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you do NOT continue to use the Visual Studio Designer as you have been. It does a very poor job of creating the XAML that we *actually* want. For example, your UI elements have all got an exact `Margin` set on them (thanks to the VS Designer I imagine) and this can make things awkward for you later on.

WPF was really designed to enable developer to use resizable controls so that the UI can resize itself when the user resizes the application. Different `Panel`s provide different sizing abilities to their child controls and you can find out more about that from the [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. However, back to your question regarding the [`Grid` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx).

Because you have used the Visual Studio Designer, your controls have *not* ended up in the `Grid` cells that you wanted, instead just being placed 'on top of', or 'in front of' them. In order to place a control into a particular `Grid` cell, you need to set the `Grid.Row` and/or `Grid.Column` Attached Properties. See this example taken from the last linked page from MSDN:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ShowGridLines="True" Width="250" Height="100">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0">2005 Products Shipped</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Quarter 1</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">Quarter 2</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">Quarter 3</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">50000</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">100000</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">150000</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3">Total Units: 300000</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Pretty much what I said, but I agree with Sheridan that learning to manipulate the xaml directly will help you long term. Incidentally, providing you create rows and columns in the designer (which presumably you didn't, because there aren't any) you can place elements within particular cells with judicious use of right-click>layout>reset-all on the element when it is over the appropriate cell. But, that said, using xaml will still give you the better (more controlled) experience. You can also use the split designer to verify that your xaml changes are giving the visual design you want.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have placed all your `BigGrid` elements into a single cell of that layout grid, and the only thing stopping them from appearing on top of each other is the fact you've defined margins. You have not defined a margin for your border, but then defined margins for **its** children, which means they'll be offset.

Really, for best layout, you want to avoid margins as much as possible and divide your `BigGrid` into rows and columns. Then place your UI into those cells. If your border is within its own cell you will not have it appear to wrap everything.